# Question about the coincidence between osculating plane and the tangent one.

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curves

I was working on differential geometry and I wondered the next question: "given a curve contained in a surface, can it always be ensured that the osculating plane at a point on the curve coincides with the tangent plane to the surface at that point?". Some idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly not. Consider any surface, for instance a sphere S, and intersect it with a transverse plane P. In the example you have a circle. The osculating plane along at any point on this curve is P, which is not the tangent plane ( they are transverse).

Comment: It is clear. Thank you so much, Thomas.